# How to display image in laravel after return image from guzzle API

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

Hi I want to display private image in my project by sending API with jwt token. I use postman to test. Postman return an image but How can I display image like post man.

Here Is my code  Controller sendApi

```
public function getIdCard($name) {
        $token = $this->getToken();
        $client = new Client(['base_uri' => env('URL_FRONTEND')]);
        $headers = [
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
        ];
        $response = $client->request('GET', 'storage/getIdCard/icQE5nwU1jQl1lrIZJmGxVs2GDIIsDjbuQo541VlwzhNTl7iEe1555385649.png', [
            'headers' => $headers
        ]);

        $response = $response->getBody()->getContents();
        return $response;
    }
```

Here is my API/ Controller [ from another project]

```
 public function getIdCard($file_name){;
        $storagePath = storage_path('app/id_card/'. $file_name);
        return Image::make($storagePath)->response();
  }
```

Here is what I get

```
PNG  IHDR��B5   pHYs���+ IDATx��yx�U�?��Nw�@B�o�Ha"ʦ� ����(.����� ��l^t��늨�D�EYe5Q�d5l��,$d�������'U眷�~��ɓ~�R���T�yC���t� ��b���`�$���z�Á�� ->W� ]�+��*������L�����"y��Hn��yj��H�Ma�ɗ�"��x��ǹϺxt�7�8���H��M�_0�ҿs�/<��o�X����h*,��,5e�Ή��1{�e��pS�,�M����z��)�R8fd5����\����SƗ�r�:J�j�ǸO�UfK�d�U��vR:��ƛ7*��v2�������dS�T礱����=c/j��\�kus��:������,�DE�Z��E���R)Y�AT�׈��!~��(�s�m@ͻ��M:"&n�����d���/�8��]�1�d���[� +5�s.tyǩ)��lF��ĬJ���us����[c�F:�U����%����/���*]���B�'Q��2]:X�݋�����q���R_�5N���"n�j� �[����}W}��#�7��{Va?��íQ���]5�����_J���¤��6NG�-͜5n?#�8Ug�z��esoT��]+����!]�E]�x����D=[�N�K���8��*5�3Ήrd�p�ps:�#%��O��-�\E^:gNg^��rq��O��iPT�\q�(�_�3{84�����kWH�o��Zw��/�Y�+��r��
```

In Postman It's return Image How can I display in like postman

**UPDATE** 
I add function in Api/controller still not working

```
public function getIdCard($file_name){;
        $storagePath = storage_path('app/id_card/'. $file_name);
        $headers = [
            "Content-type: image/png",
        ];
        return response()->file($storagePath, $headers);
   }
```

**UPDATE 2 **

I'm working on 2 project 
- The first project I return API return response()->file($storagePath, $headers);
-Then I use post man and it's return image
- The second project I want to get image from API  and I use

```
   $response = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

It's return text/html  How to display it into image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what's your Image class, so I would say how to do it with built in functions.

`return response()->file($pathToFile, $headers);`

Most probably with calling the file method you won't need any headers (as second param) but in case you need one, try to use something like ["Content-type: image/png"]

Comment: I update my question. Postman return an image but in my proj it didn't display name .

Comment: It works for me. Can you show your headers in Google Chrome dev tools? http://joxi.ru/1A5vpbXHDGxJ8r

`return response()->file(__DIR__.'/1.jpg', [
            "Content-type: image/png",
        ]);`

Comment: well l, Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8; But in post man I got Content-Type →image/png

Comment: I updated mu question. I dont know how to display it =[. try to do this 5 hr still not workingg

Comment: Postman is just a kind of another browser. It sent some request headers and read result with response headers. Most probably postman works wrong or just overrides the wrong result because somewhere you've specified that you expect a picture. You have to find a problem why you're typing content-type image and getting html. Focus on it. Probably server misconfiguration or whatever, the code itself is fine. (try php artisan serve)

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution:

```
$data = $response->getBody()->getContents();
$base64 = 'data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($data);
echo '<img src="'.$base64.'">';
```